# max size of JLabels being overridden by text width?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` in which one column represents the size occupied by a folder on disk.  Each row represents one folder, and this column has a list of rectangles; the width of each rectangle represents a percentage of the size occupied by one type of file.  Here's a picture:

[image: example of wide layout]

I do this by creating a `JLabel` for each file type in a row, then, in the `getTableCellRenderer()` method, I have an array of `JLabels`, one per file type.  That method sets the preferred and maximum sizes of the `JLabel` to be the column height and the percentage of the column width for each label.

My problem comes when the picture is narrowed; the following was made by narrowing the frame of the program illustrated above:

[image: example of narrow layout]

As you can see, the percentage representation is gone, and the width of the `JLabel`s now appear based on the width of the text, not on the preferred/max sizes set.  If I narrow the window further, the percentage calculations again appear to take precedence; it is only in a narrow width range that I see this behavior.

Is there another way to do this?  Do I have to draw rectangles and use `drawText()` instead of using the `FlowLayout` and text elision that already exists?

Here's the code that sets the characteristics of the `JLabel`s:

```
sizeBlockDimensions[i].setSize(newWidth, rowHeight);
sizeBlockLabels[i].setPreferredSize(sizeBlockDimensions[i]);
sizeBlockLabels[i].setMaximumSize(sizeBlockDimensions[i]);
sizeBlockLabels[i].setBackground(color);
sizeBlockLabels[i].setText(labelText);
sizeBlockLabels[i].setVisible(true);
i++;
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: post an SSCCE and set GBC or BoxLayout (eventually FlowLayout) for JLabel, my question is how do you store those value in XxxTableModel and how do you want to do, because you must to store (in XxxTableModel) only value for XxxRenderer

Comment: @mKorbel I do not understand your question; you say "how do you store those value in XxxTableModel" but I don't know what value you mean.  I cannot store the width there, the width is only available at layout time.  The percentages are stored for each type in the cell, but I don't understand how that affects the layout.  I was hoping someone could comment on the overriding of setMaximumSize of a JLabel by the width of its text, and/or another way to approach the whole thing.

Comment: post an SSCCE with hardcoded value for JTable generated attn. image(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> instead of using the FlowLayout

You should be able to use the [Relative Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). It was specifically designed for relative sizes and should adjust automatically as the space available changes.

Comment: Thanks for reading my question and taking the effort to understand it; with the class you offered and two other lines of code changed, the problem is solved.  I still want to know what's happening in the original, but it's secondary to solving the problem.  And I intend to make a study of RelativeLayout to understand how to write a layout manager.